# How to implement smooth scrolling Canvas animation in Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, canvas, android-jetpack-compose

I send a stream of `shapes` to the drawing pipeline. At any point in time, `shapes` contains the number of items that can fill the screen's width or less.

Here's the drawing widget:

```
@Composable
fun ShapeWidget(shapes: List<Shape>, size: Float, spacing: Float, screenWidth: Float) {
    val color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.tertiary
    Canvas(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        onDraw = {
            shapes.forEachIndexed { i, s ->
                val x = screenWidth - ((size + spacing) * i)
                when (s.type) {
                    Type.RECT -> {
                        drawRect(
                            color = color,
                            size = Size(size, size),
                            topLeft = Offset(x, this.center.y - size / 2),
                        )
                    }
                    Type.CIRCLE -> {
                        drawCircle(
                            color = color,
                            radius = size / 2,
                            center = Offset(x + spacing * 2, center.y)
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    )
}
```

I want to achieve an effect similar to the marquee text effect in Android Views. The shapes start drawing from the right (of the screen) and scroll to the left as more shapes are drawn.

The code above does that, but the animation is janky; it doesn't give the illusion that the shapes are moving. It looks like the shapes are jumping, which is not what I want. [This is what it looks like currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OgOxk.jpg).

Please, do you have an idea how to fix this?

Comment: Nothing seems wrong with current snippet. How you set spacing determines which kind of motion you will get. It depends on interpolator and time interval, key frames and so on. You need to share how it changes

Comment: You're drawing shapes at fixed positions (based on `size` and `spacing`) so the effect is more like an animation on a scoreboard (and your scroll speed is probably too fast for that style). If you want smooth scrolling, you need to offset *everything* by an amount that changes over time, e.g. `val x = offset + ((size + spacing) * i)` where decreasing `offset` makes everything move to the left. That's a very general idea, you might need to consider things like an offset that adjusts when you remove an item, and I don't know how compose handles things like interpolation - just giving you ideas!